# Help with reducing $71^{71}$ mod $17$ using Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am self studying number theory and have come across a problem involving Fermat's Little Theorem that I cannot seem to solve. The question asks to find the least remainder of $71^{71} \pmod {17}$.

I started by noticing that $71^{71}=71^{(17-1)4} \times 71^{7}$, which, by Fermat's, means my answer is congruent to $71^{7} \mod17$.

Is this the right first step, or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are going in right direction

Comment: What would be a good next step? I'm not sure how to reduce $71^{7}$?

Comment: Reduce the base $71$ as well and see what it equals to $\mod 17$

Comment: Ah ok, now I get that it is congruent to $3^{7}$. Would I just take out powers of 3 until I get a number close to 17?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay so you are doing it right!
First you do as what OP did reduce $71$ to relate it with Fermat's little theorem
$71^{71} \equiv 71^{4(17-1)}\times 71^7 \mod 17$
Now, $(71^{16})^4 \equiv 1^4 \mod 17$ (Using Fermat's little theorem)
Which means we are left with $71^7 \mod 17$
$71 \equiv 4(17-1) +7\mod 17$
$\implies 71 \equiv 3 \mod 17$
$\implies 71^7 \equiv 3^7 \mod 17$
$\implies 3^{4} \cdot 3^{3} \equiv 81 \times 27 \mod 17$
$\implies 81 \times 27 \equiv (-4)(-7)\mod 17$
$\implies 28 \equiv 11 \mod 17$

Comment: Thank you very much! You work and suggestions were very insightful.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).